# DUPLICATE_VALUE Error while inserting a knowledge article

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I am receiving the following error while inserting a knowledge article through the class (not a test class but a regular handler class) when called from Trigger.

> DUPLICATE_VALUE, The URL Name cannot match the draft or published version of any other article

I tried using execute anonymous (Using different URLName which won't match existing draft or published version of any other article) and it works.

```
Known_Issue__kav knownIssue = new Known_Issue__kav();
knownIssue.Title = 'NewTitle';
knownIssue.UrlName = 'salesforce'; //this URLName doesn't match the draft or published version of any other article. Also if I use any random text instead, I get an error.
insert knownIssue;
```

Comment: What's your question? _Does_ the `UrlName` match the draft or published version of any other article?

Comment: Have a look of this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMqYQAW)

Comment: @DavidReed Using this code in apex class calling it from trigger doesn't work and gives me the error. But when I do the same using "Execute from Anonymous Window" It works.

Comment: So, @Sandeep, _is_ this code running in a test class? Your previous comment suggested it was not. _Does_ the `UrlName` match? You haven't given us enough information here to go on. Please [edit] your question rather than posting more comments.

Comment: @DavidReed Updated